# Define object keys but infer values

Tags: typescript

I have two objects:

```
const paths = {
  login: '/login',
  admin: '/admin/:userId'
}

const pathBuilder = {
  login: () => '/login',
  admin: (userId: string) => `/admin/${userId}`,
}
```

Now I would like to type the `pathBuilder` object so that it has the same keys as the object `paths` but tell TypeScript to infer the type of values from it.

I've tried using `Record<keyof typeof paths, any>` or `{ [key in keyof typeof paths]: any }` but I end up with an object that has keys typed and value set to `any`.

The only way I found it to work was to do additional object casting like so:

```
const paths = {
  login: '/login',
  admin: '/admin/:userId'
}
type Paths = typeof paths;

const pathBuilder = {
  login: () => '/login',
  admin: (userId: string) => `/admin/${userId}`,
}
type Builder = typeof pathBuilder;

// now this typedPathBuilder object will have keys from paths and values from pathBuilder
const typedPathBuilder: {
  [Key in keyof Definitions]: Builder[Key];
} = pathBuilder;
```

This is not ideal though.

Comment: Translating the constrained-generic-identity-function solution from the other question here yields [this code](https://tsplay.dev/yNaq0N).

Comment: thanks @jcalz ! looks like it is what I'm looking for